# Kotlin | Spring | WebFlux | WebFilter | subscriberContext is empty on error

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, kotlin-coroutines

I have this code snippet here:

```
@Component
class ResponseHeadersWebFilter : WebFilter {
    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        exchange.response.beforeCommit {
            Mono.subscriberContext().doOnNext { context ->
                context.get<Map<String, String>>(CONTEXT_MAP).let {
                    exchange.response.headers.apply {
                        add(HEADER_REQUEST_ID, it[METADATA_REQUEST_ID])
                        add(HEADER_USER, it[METADATA_USER])
                    }
                }
            }.then()
        }
        val contextMap = exchange.request.headers.toSingleValueMap().let {
            mapOf(
                    METADATA_REQUEST_ID to it[HEADER_REQUEST_ID],
                    METADATA_USER to it[HEADER_USER]
            )
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange).subscriberContext(Context.of(CONTEXT_MAP, contextMap))
    }
}
```

The idea is to put request headers into context, and then add them from context to the response (based on [this article](https://ndportmann.com/passing-context-with-spring-webflux/))

It works if the request is processed successfully

However, if there is an exception then the context becomes empty

I checked from within the relevant @ExceptionHandler method (using coroutineContext[ReactorContext] in a suspending function) and it sees the headers in the context. But when it moves on to WebFilter's beforeCommit, somewhere along the way it loses the context. Moreover, @ExceptionHandler and WebFilter are in the same thread and the same coroutine

Any idea where to look? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Hey, if you were able to resolve the issue, would be awesome if you could post it as the correct answer.